# How can I get my Twitter Bootstrap buttons to right align?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-2

I have a simple demo here:

```
<ul>
    <li>One <input class="btn pull-right" value="test"></li>
    <li>Two <input class="btn pull-right" value="test2"></li>
</ul>
```

I have an unordered list and for each list item I wish to have text on the left and then a right aligned button.  I have tried to use pull-right but this completely messes up the alignment.  What am I doing wrong?

```html
<link href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<ul>
  <li>One <input class="btn pull-right" value="test"></li>
  <li>Two <input class="btn  pull-right" value="test2" </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged with [tag:twitter-bootstrap-3] and [tag:twitter-bootstrap-2] as well as [tag:twitter-bootstrap]?

Comment: Because it's relevant to all versions since 3/2013

Answer (score 786, accepted):

Insert `pull-right` into the class attribute and let bootstrap arrange the buttons.

For **Bootstrap 2.3**, see: http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#misc > Helper classes > .pull-right.

---

For **Bootstrap 3**, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#helper-classes > Helper classes.

---

For **Bootstrap 4**, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/#responsive

The `pull-right` command was removed and replaced with `float-right` or in general to `float-{sm,md,lg,xl}-{left,right,none}`

---

For **Boostrap 5**, see: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/

The closest solution would be `float-end`.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. In the question the example code is already using `pull-right`.

Comment: @guival I was wondering the same thing. https://stackoverflow.com/a/26546770/470749 implies that using `button` instead of `input` will make a difference.

Comment: float-end worked for me

Answer (score 255):

In twitter bootstrap 3 try the class **pull-right**

```
class="btn pull-right"
```

Comment: Not anymore, it was deprecated as of v 3.1 : http://getbootstrap.com/components/#dropdowns-alignment

Comment: +1 for highlighting the change. But that depreciation is only for drop down menu which has been replaced by .dropdown-menu-right. Its has not been deprecated as a whole.

Comment: you are right, the documentation says `we've deprecated .pull-right on dropdown menus`

Comment: I had to use pull-right in the outer btn-group div: <div class="btn-group pull-right">

Comment: `pull-right` uses `float: right`, thereby collapsing vertical contents on top of each other. Wrap the button with `text-right` DIV like this -`<div class="text-right">button...</div>`

Answer (score 161):

"pull-right" class may not be the right way because in uses "float: right" instead of text-align.

Checking the bootstrap 3 css file i found "text-right" class on line 457. This class should be the right way to align the text to the right.

Some code:
For Bootstrap 3 & 4

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="text-right">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Default</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For bootstrap 5

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="text-end">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Default</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is better than pull-right because it prevents the vertical content from collapsing on top of each other and avoids having to add more mark-up just to workaround that.

Comment: Thank you. The problem with "pull-right" is that it removes any margins from the buttons. This maintains margins but moves the elements to right. Perfect!

Comment: Why text-right must be in div containg this button instead of just `class="btn btn-default text-right"` in button???

Comment: This did the trick for me, but now (bootstrap 5) you'll have to use `text-end`.

Comment: Answer updated, thanks!

Answer (score 80):

**Update 2019 - Bootstrap 4.0.0**

The `pull-right` class is now **`float-right`** in Bootstrap 4...

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">One <input type="button" class="btn float-right" value="test"></div>
        <div class="col-12">Two <input type="button" class="btn float-right" value="test"></div>
    </div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/nTobetXAwb

It's also better to not align the ul list and use block elements for the rows.

**Is `float-right` still not working?**

Remember that **Bootstrap 4 is now flexbox**, and many elements are `display:flex` which can prevent float-right from working. In some cases, the util classes like `align-self-end` or `ml-auto` work to right align elements that are inside a flexbox container like a Bootstrap 4 .row, Card or Nav.

Also remember that `text-right` still works on inline elements.

[Bootstrap 4 align right examples](https://www.codeply.com/go/nTobetXAwb)

---

**Bootstrap 3**

Use the `pull-right` class.

Comment: They're working for me, but you shouldn't need to rely on the links. Read the answer for an explanation on how to align right.

Answer (score 19):

Use `button` tag instead of `input` and use `pull-right` class.

`pull-right` class totally messes up both of your buttons, but you can fix this by defining custom margin on the right side.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-sm RbtnMargin" type="button">Save</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-sm"  type="button">Cancel</button>
```

Then use the following CSS for the class

```
.RbtnMargin { margin-left: 5px; }
```

Answer (score 19):

Adding to the accepted answer, when working within containers and columns that have built in padding from bootstrap, I sometimes have a full stretched column with a child div that does the pulling to be the way to go.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="pull-right">
            <p>I am right aligned, factoring in container column padding</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternately, have all your columns add up to your total number of grid columns (12 by default) along with  having the first column be offset.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
        This content and its sibling..
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
        are right aligned as a whole thanks to the offset on the first column and the sum of the columns used is the total available (12).
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 12):

Sorry for replying to an older already answered question, but I thought I'd point out a couple of reasons that your jsfiddle does not work, in case others check it out and wonder why the pull-right class as described in the accepted answer doesn't work there.

1. the url to the bootstrap.css file is invalid. (perhaps it worked when you asked the question).
2. you should add the attribute: type="button" to your input element, or it won't be rendered as a button - it will be rendered as an input box.  Better yet, use the `<button>` element instead.
3. Additionally, because pull-right uses floats, you will get some staggering of the button layout because each LI does not have enough height to accommodate the height of the button. Adding some line-height or min-height css to the LI would address that.

working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3ejqufp6/

```
<ul>
  <li>One <input type="button" class="btn pull-right" value="test"/></li>
  <li>Two <input type="button" class="btn pull-right" value="test2"/></li>
</ul>
```

(I also added a min-width to the buttons as I couldn't stand the look of a ragged right-justified look to the buttons because of varying widths :) )

Answer (score 11):

Using the Bootstrap `pull-right` helper didn't work for us because it uses `float: right`, which [forces `inline-block` elements to become `block`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo).  And when the `.btn`s become `block`, they lose the natural margin that `inline-block` was providing them as quasi-textual elements.

So instead we used `direction: rtl;` on the parent element, which causes the text inside that element to layout from right to left, and that causes `inline-block` elements to layout from right to left, too.  You can use LESS like the following to prevent children from being laid out `rtl` too:

```
/* Flow the inline-block .btn starting from the right. */
.btn-container-right {
  direction: rtl;

  * {
    direction: ltr;
  }
}
```

and use it like:

```
<div class="btn-container-right">
    <button class="btn">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

In **Bootstrap 4**: Try this way with Flexbox. See documentation in [getbootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Example 1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Example 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

**For Bootstrap 5:**

Documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/float/

use `.float-end` in the element for right alignment.
You possibly have to add `.clearfix` in the parent element if you move ex a button to the right and don't want the following element to slide up.

Answer (score 4):

Apply `pull-right` class for the button.
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats -> Helper classes

This link will help

Answer (score 4):

Pull right was depreciated as of v3.1.0 .
Just a heads up.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#callout-dropdown-pull-right

Comment: `pull-right` is deprecated on `dropdown-menu`. It can still be used for other components.

Answer (score 3):

Now you need to add `.dropdown-menu-right` to the existing `.dropdown-menu` element. `pull-right` is not supported anymore.

More info here http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-dropdowns

Answer (score 2):

```
<ul>
    <li class="span4">One <input class="btn btn-small" value="test"></li>
    <li class="span4">Two <input class="btn btn-small" value="test2"></li>
</ul>
```

One way would be to apply this style to your list items in order to keep them inline

**or**

```
<ul>
    <li>One <input class="btn" value="test"></li>
    <li>Two <input class="btn" value="test2"></li>
</ul>
```

**in CSS**

```
li {
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 5px;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

Comment: For me this puts both list items on a single line

Answer (score 2):

Can you try a custom CSS aside the bootstrap CSS to see if any changes. Try

```
.move-rigth{
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

If it works then you can try manipulating what you have or adding other formatting to this and achieving what you desire. Because you are using bootstrap doesn't mean if it doesn't offer you what you want then you just manage it. You are working with your codes and so you command it to do as you say. 
Cheers!

Comment: no need for custom css, as the other answer shows everything needed is included in the bootstrap

Comment: @chrisweb What if you have some other plugins which share same CSS class unknown to you and conflicting issues, what do you do? Sit and watch than create a custom css and move on? The OP never specified if any other plugins were added that might share same css classes.

Answer (score 2):

you can also use blank columns to give spaces on left

like

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8"></div>  <!-- blank space increase or decrease it by column # -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <button id="saveedit" name="saveedit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Demo ::
[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1vjan5hm/)

Answer (score 1):

From **Bootstrap V3.3.1** the following CSS style will solve this issue

```
.modal-open{
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Note: I tried all the suggestions in posts above and all addresses older versions and do not provide a fix to newset bootstrap versions.

Answer (score 1):

```
<p align="right">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</p>
```

Comment: If you could include an explanation to accompany the code it will assist the original poster.

Answer (score 1):

For bootstrap `5.1.3` the attribute `float-end` works for me:

```
<div class="row mt-2 float-end">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <button class="btn btn-warning" >Do something else</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary ml-2">Do primary action</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using the buttons as part of your lists. And because the vertical margin between list items is too low to place the buttons in between it messes the alignments up. I would place one of the buttons on top of the list and another one beneath them so that it would look like what you expect!

```
<ul>
<input class="btn pull-right" value="test">
<li>One</li> 
<li>Two</li>
<input class="btn pull-right" value="test2"> 
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

for bootstrap 4 [documentation](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment)

```
  <div class="row justify-content-end">
    <div class="col-4">
      Start of the row
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      End of the row
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What does this have to do with align right and buttons?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 