# Add pulled-right button in bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I've been using this bootstrap example:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/examples/offcanvas/

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

     <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3 my-3 text-white-50 bg-dark rounded box-shadow">
    <img class="mr-3" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-outline.svg" alt="" width="48" height="48">
    <div class="lh-100">
      <h6 class="mb-0 text-white lh-100">Bootstrap</h6>
      <small>Since 2011</small>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I wanted to add a button on the right side of this but pull-right won't work:
[Desired result](http://prntscr.com/k3nue1)

Any ideas how can I work it out in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `small` tag out of the `1h-100` div and add class `ml-auto` to it

```
 <small class="ml-auto text-white">Since 2011</small>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3 my-3 text-white-50 bg-dark rounded box-shadow">
  <img class="mr-3" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-outline.svg" alt="" width="48" height="48">
  <div class="lh-100">
    <h6 class="mb-0 text-white lh-100">Bootstrap</h6>
    
  </div>
  <small class="ml-auto text-white">Since 2011</small>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeffet
I have modified your code, Kindly have a look over it. It seems fine on my browser, i have use float properties based on Custom CSS Styling.
Feel free to ask any question
 If the Code Solve your problem, then Vote Up to Acknowledge our effort.

Thank You.

Best Wishes,

```
<html>
<style>
.mb-0{
float:left;
}
.small{
color:red;
float:right;
margin-left:70%;
margin-top:20px;
}
.clear{
clear:both;
}
</style>
  <div class="d-flex align-items-center p-3 my-3 text-white-50 bg-purple rounded box-shadow">
    <img class="mr-3" src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/assets/brand/bootstrap-outline.svg" alt="" width="48" height="48">
    <div class="lh-100 row">
      <h6 class="mb-0 text-white lh-100 col-md-6">Bootstrap</h6>
      <small style="" class="small">Since 2011</small>
      <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes @D.Yeffet Let me Manage the Code for float right

Comment: Kindly give me 2 minutes

Comment: Wow @D.Yeffet Magic happens the Code Works : ) Let me share the Edited Code.

Comment: Kindly check the Code Now @D.Yeffet It's working fine now, check and let me know , if correct kindly Vote Up. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

As `pull-right` is replaced with `float-right` in bootstrap 4 suggested by [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15446189/how-can-i-get-my-twitter-bootstrap-buttons-to-right-align)  so try using that.

Comment: do you have some custom css applied ?